# What is the cron expression to run salesforce batch for every 5 hours every day

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

What is the cron expression to run salesforce batch  for every 5 hours every day,
I tried using below cron but not working.
0 0 0/5 ? * * *
So can you please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try below Cron expression?

```
String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0,5,10,15,20 * * ?';
```